# jQuery’s css() lags when work with animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I’m trying `$('.pic_3dwave_01b')` and `$('.pic_3dwave_01a')` could work at the same time, but sometimes `$('.pic_3dwave_01b')` was lagging (delayed), I think maybe `css()`'s efficiency is bad, do you have any suggestion?

```
$('.story_01').fadeIn(10, function() {
    $('.pic_3dwave_01b').css({'opacity': 0, 'top': 54})
    $('.pic_3dwave_01a').animate({'opacity': 1, 'top': 94}, 600);
    $('.story_01 .pic_3dwave_02').animate({'opacity': 1}, 600);
    $('.textbox_s1').animate({'opacity': 1, 'left': 70}, 400, function() {
        calCount();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle.

Comment: You should css 3 instead. it ll perform better and faster.